# TCPlistener server-client and client-server ( send message to client from server)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

All i want to do is send message to client from server. I try a lot of tutorial etc. but still can't send message from server to client. 
Send from client to server is simple and have it in code. When client Send "HI" to server i want to respond Hi to client. But dunno what should i add to my code. Can someone help me with that? Please don't do it like duplicate i know there is a lot of similar topic but can't find solution.

Server code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
  TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip, Convert.ToInt32(8555));
  TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);
   try
   {
     server.Start();
     Console.WriteLine("Server started...");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
   };

   while (true)
   {
      client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
      byte[] receivetBuffer = new byte[100];
      NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
      stream.Read(receivetBuffer, 0, receivetBuffer.Length);
      StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
      foreach(byte b in receivetBuffer)
      {
          if (b.Equals(59))
          {
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            msg.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
          }
      }
       ////Resive message :
       if (msg.ToString() =="HI")
       {
          ///@EDIT 1
          ///// HERE Is SENDING  MESSAGE TO CLIENT//////////  
          int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("You said HI" + 1); 
          byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];
          sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("You said HI" + ";");
          stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length); 
       }
}
```

Client code:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
     string serverIP = "localhost";
     int port = Convert.ToInt32(8555);
     TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);
     int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("HI"+ 1);
     byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];
     sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HI" + ";");
     NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
     stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);


    ///////////////////////////////HERE I WANT A read message from server/
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     stream.Close();
     client.Close();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
       ex.ToString();
     }
}
```

Comment: well while its server + client, have you tried just writing to the stream like you do in the client?

Comment: I edited my code for Server and added sending message to client. but how can i reseive this?

Comment: TCP is not *messaging*. It's a stream of bytes in each direction and the number of bytes you put into that stream with a call to `Write` is *not* guaranteed to be matched by some call of `Read` getting that same number of bytes. You need to pay attention to what `Read` returns and if you want messaging, *you* have to implement it atop TCP (or switch to a protocol that does this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Here is my version of client and server ,feel free to ask if any reference problem ,the client wait for server to (online) then if server is online connect with it.

Method to Connect with Server

```
 private void Connectwithserver(ref TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
             //this is server ip and server listen port
            server = new TcpClient("192.168.100.7", 8080);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            //exceptionsobj.WriteException(ex);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            RunBoTClient();

        }
    }

 byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    string stringData;
    TcpClient client;

    private void RunClient()
    {
         NetworkStream ns;
        Connectwithserver(ref client);

         while (true)
        {
            ns = client.GetStream();
            //old
            // ns.ReadTimeout = 50000;
            //old
            ns.ReadTimeout = 50000;
            ns.WriteTimeout = 50000;

            int recv = default(int);
            try
            {


                recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                //exceptionsobj.WriteException(ex);
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
               //try to reconnect if server not respond 
                RunClient();
            }
         //READ SERVER RESPONSE/MESSAGE
            stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        }

    }
```

**Server**

```
IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        //---incoming client connected---
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

        //---read incoming stream---
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

        //---convert the data received into a string---
        string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Console.WriteLine("Received : " + dataReceived);

         //IF YOU WANT TO WRITE BACK TO CLIENT USE
       string yourmessage = console.ReadLine();
        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yourmessage);
        //---write back the text to the client---
        Console.WriteLine("Sending back : " + yourmessage );
        nwStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
        client.Close();
    }
    listener.Stop();
```

Comment: I edited my code for Server and added sending message to client. but how can i reseive this? I did it watching your code.

Comment: @adam if you are using a router run the client code on pc1 and run the server code on pc2 connected with same router then run server program with the private ip of that pc then give that server private ip and port to client then run the client both will communicate

Comment: I base on my own code, your is example.I now need to read message from server.

Comment: @adam i have edited the code now server will ask you to input string then send back to the client

Comment: I know how to write back look my code  please... I want to read on client now.

Comment: @adam I have updated now you can read server response on client side,see client code "stringData"